# How to asynchronously set the preloadedstate in redux toolkit?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage, redux-toolkit

This is my current configureStore settings

```
const loadStateFromStorage = () => {
  window.chrome.storage.local.get(["test-something"]).then((result) => {
    return result['test-something'];
  });
  // if (localStorage.getItem('work-parallel-state') !== null) {
  //   return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('work-parallel-state'));
  // }
}

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    tasks: taskReducer
  },
  preloadedState: loadStateFromStorage(),
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat([storeStateToStorage])
})
```

preloadedState expects data to be synchronously obtained from loadStateFromStorage, how do I update it asynchronously?
Is there an option to provide loadStateFromStorage as an async, something like

```
loadStateFromStorage = async () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  window.chrome.storage.local.get(["test-something"]).then((result) => {
    //console.log("Value currently is " + result['test-something']);
    resolve(result['test-something']);
  });
})
}

preloadedState: loadStateFromStorage
```

I currently have a hacky solution to run with but was hoping for a more elegant solution:
My current solution is:

//index.js

```
window.chrome.storage.local.get(["multitask-state"]).then((result) => {
  const initialState = JSON.parse(result['multitask-state'])
  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={storeWithInitialData(initialState)}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );

});
```

//store.js

```
export const storeWithInitialData = (initialData) => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: {
      tasks: taskReducer,
      timer: timerReducer
    },
    preloadedState: initialData,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat([storeStateToStorage])
  })
}
```

Comment: I had this same issue. I ended up enabling top level await.  Was already using TSC and Webpack so it was pretty simple to enable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's a great solution here.  Your "hacky solution" is not far off from what I would do, and what `redux-persist` does with the [`PersistGate`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/PersistGate.md) component. You do need to delay rendering of the app until you have loaded the `preloadedState`.  The main improvement that you can make is to show some sort of loading UI.

```
const loadStateFromStorage = async () => {
    const result = await window.chrome.storage.local.get(["test-something"]);
    return result['test-something'];
}
```

```
const PreloadProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [preloaded, setPreloaded] = useState({ isReady: false, preloadedState: undefined });

    useEffect(() => {
        loadStateFromStorage()
            .then(state => setPreloaded({ isReady: true, preloadedState: state }))
            .catch(() => setPreloaded({ isReady: true, preloadedState: undefined }));
    }, [setPreloaded]);

    return preloaded.isReady ? (
        <Provider store={storeWithInitialData(preloaded.preloadedState)}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    ) : (
        <div>Loading...</div>
    );
}
```

^ Note: this might need to be memoized.  I haven't run this code so you should make sure that the `storeWithInitialData` function is only executed once.

```
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <PreloadProvider>
            <App />
        </PreloadProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```